# How to block a python function until interaction with matplotlib is over

Tags: python, matplotlib, interactive

I wrote a python function that uses matplotlib to plot some data and measure user interaction. For simplicity's sake let's assume I want to count the number of times the user clicks on the plot:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


def count_clicks(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    counter = 0
    done = False

    def onclick(event):
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1

    def onclose(event):
        nonlocal counter
        nonlocal done
        print(counter)
        done = True

    ax.plot(data)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', onclose)

    return counter


count_clicks(range(10))
```

I would like the function to wait until the user closes the figure before returning, but currently, it's returning right away, leaving the figure detached (i.e. clicks are still counted, and when closing the figure the correct count is printed).
What am I doing wrong?

I tried:

```
while not done:
    continue
```

before the return statement, which hanged the plot and didn't let it show.
I also tried `plt.show()` and `plt.ion()` to no avail

Answer (score 0):

Interactive mode appears to be turned on in your environment. You have to turn it off and force the draw with `plt.show()`.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.ioff()

def count_clicks(data):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    counter = 0
    done = False

    def onclick(event):
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1

    def onclose(event):
        nonlocal counter
        nonlocal done
        print(counter)
        done = True

    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event', onclick)
    fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', onclose)

    ax.plot(data)
    plt.show()

    return counter

count_clicks(range(10))
```

Comment: That indeed blocks execution, but for some reason execusion won't resume after I close the figure

Comment: What do you mean with "execution won't resume"? Does the print statement trigger?

Comment: The print statement is triggered, but the return statement is never reached.

Comment: Are you this exact code or something else? How do you know the return statement is never reached? Also, how are you running the code? In a plain python shell, ipython, jupyter notebook, or something else entirely?

Comment: I'm running this exact code (for debugging) in Pycharm's python console.
I tried both a breakpoint at the return statement and a print statement between the `plt.show()` and the `return` statements. Code after `plt.show()` is never reached.
Now that you mentioned it, though, I tried running it independently (i.e. using "run" over the script) and it does work. It seems to be some problem (or some settings issue?) with the Pycharm console.